# Get specific table depending on week ASP.NET MVC LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

as the title says. I'am trying to get data out of the database depending on the week which the logged in user chooses.

My database table stampings has has an UserId, Timestamp and StampingType columns!

Model:

```
public partial class StampingModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string StampingType { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

}

View:

```
@model Aviato.Models.StampingModel <input type="text" id="weekTxtBox"/> <input type="submit" value="Choose" id="weekStampBtn"/>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetWeekStamp(StampingModel model)
    {
        var getWeek = db.Stampings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Timestamp == model.Timestamp); //This I dont quite know.

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Stampings()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

JavaScript (Optional, if there is an easier way, please let me know):

```
$("#weekStampBtn").click(function() {

    var weekTxtBox = $("#weekTxtBox").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "User/GetWeekStamp",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
            weekTxtBox: weekTxtBox
        }
    });

});
```

How should my coode look like? Especially my LINQ/Lambda expression...

Comment: What is your question? Does the code you have posted not work in some way? If so please explain  what the problem is.

Comment: The question title is a bit confusing too. Do you mean you have a 1 table of data with dates, and you want to get the rows which have dates within a specific week, e.g. from Sunday 5th January to Saturday 11th January? And if so, what does the user put into weekTxtBox to get that data?

Comment: The user are supposed to  being able to see their in and out stampings depending on the week date they've choosen. And I need to know how to do that, how is the expression supposed to look like while checking the Database?

I have currently 4 pieces of test data in my stamping table, and I want to display it ofcourse...

Comment: -1 Please, google LINQ and see some basic tutorials or samples. Your question is not a problem at all. The problem is you don't know anything about LINQ.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me some relevant links? Im not the best Googler either, so a little help would be very much apprecieated.

Comment: [101 linq samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a method that gives you the week of the year:

```
private int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime d)
        {
            var cal = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
            return cal.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1), System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        }
```

and then change your code to:

```
var getWeek = db.Stampings.FirstOrDefault(s => GetWeekOfYear(s.Timestamp) == GetWeekOfYear(model.Timestamp));
```

Comment: Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetWeekOfYear(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Red lined: "var getWeek = db.Stampings.FirstOrDefault(s => GetWeekOfYear(s.Timestamp) == GetWeekOfYear(model.Timestamp));"

Comment: Add the static keyword to the method: private static int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime d)

Comment: @Qvadriologic I tested my solution and it works with the static keyword